# Assembler used by golang when building with and without cgo

Tags: gcc, assembly, go, package, cgo

Let's say I have a golang package, which contains some assembly code:

```
 demopkg/
   source1.go
   source2.go
   asm_amd64.s
```

If I try to build it using `go build`, toolchain will use `go tool asm` to assemble the *.s files.

But if I add Cgo to the mixture, by putting a single `import "C"` into any of the sources, go will switch to gcc assembler.

I can see it by executing `go build -n`. Calls to the `/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/asm` from the first case get replaced by calls to `gcc`. Besides that, it starts complaining about broken syntax.

Is this behaviour documented, so I can rely on it for the maintaining of my package? Can I force `go build` to use one exact assembler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's in the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

> When the Go tool sees that one or more Go files use the special import
>   "C", it will look for other non-Go files in the directory and compile
>   them as part of the Go package. Any .c, .s, or .S files will be
>   compiled with the C compiler. Any .cc, .cpp, or .cxx files will be
>   compiled with the C++ compiler. Any .h, .hh, .hpp, or .hxx files will
>   not be compiled separately, but, if these header files are changed,
>   the C and C++ files will be recompiled. The default C and C++
>   compilers may be changed by the CC and CXX environment variables,
>   respectively; those environment variables may include command line
>   options.

Comment: Oh wow, I saw this page a dozen of times, but I never noticed the part about .s files. I guess the only way to avoid this feature is to split packages...